# Android studio 2.2 and gradle 2.14.1 slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've a Lenovo y510p laptop with i7 and 12 GB of ram.
Android studio seems to run smoothly but whenever i try to compile and gradle start to work, it takes approximatly 11 minute to complete his task.
It get stuck at:
":app:mergeDebugResources"
then, after a lot of time, it succesful finish to build.
How could i make it run normaly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2. and I  have a laptop Lenovo I5 with 16 Gigabytes but it was super slow on Windows 7.

Impossible to work!
I installed Ubuntu as a secondary Operational System and became more then 10 times faster.
I suggest you install the Linux Ubuntu Operational system as a secondary Operational System and then Install Android Studio for Linux.
May be you can try use Linux Ubuntu to make Android Studio faster.